# What do you call those pubs that are run in ruins and soon-to-be-demolished buildings?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are famous pubs in Budapest and Berlin which are operated in abandoned or soon to be demolished buildings.

Some call them ruin pubs, but I'm not quite sure that's the correct name.

Comment: A pub in ruins... is a ruin pub; it makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> At night time, Budapest holds a truly epic secret. I talked a bit about drinking in the streets of Hong Kong last month. Well Budapest has one up on Hong Kong: Introducing Ruin Pubs. This concept is basically a bar in a derelict or ruined building. It’s very quirky, very cheap, very good for meeting people and you can draw on the walls! Some of these are so popular that the Germans have taken the concept to Berlin. Others are literally hidden and unless someone shows you where it is then you won’t have a clue!

[Article on Budapest](http://www.pronomad.net/my-new-home-why-budapest-is-remarkably-awesome/) It seems that *ruin pubs* is the proper name for those establishments. You can see the list of them (not sure if it's a full list) on [ruinpubs.com](http://ruinpubs.com/)

Comment: OH right, I misunderstood the question. I though it was about pubs which had fallen into ruin. I now see that it means ruins which are used as pubs. I had not met the concept before.

Comment: I know the site, but it is a hungarian one, so they could make up this word :)

Comment: @KARASZI István Most probably they did exactly that. But that's how those pubs are known now. And since Hungarians were the authors of this concept, they have the right to name it too, haven't they?

Comment: Only when it's appropriate. They could call it awesome pubs as well - which they are actually :) - but that would not refer their main property correctly.

Comment: I don't believe there was any established English phrase for this concept, and *ruin pub* is a great name for it, so clearly it has become the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a word for *pubs* in that state specifically, but a word for such buildings in general is **derelict**.

Comment: How appropriate: a bunch of derelicts being derelict in a derelict.

Comment: @Kit: Thwack. (Really, you should know better than that. Hmph.)